# CSS Drop-Down with <select> not useable in IE

Tags: html, css, forms, select, drop-down-menu

A client at work has requested that we convert a form into a drop-down menu on their navigation. Not a problem in itself, but we are not allowed to use any JS here. If we can't come up with any other fix though they will allow a small vanilla JS script to deal with the problem.

**The Problem**

The  input on the form cannot be used in Internet Explorer as the entire menu hides on clicking on the form element.

I have made a [JS Fiddle](http://cloud.danielgroves.net/xbK0) of the issue, and would appreciate any help anyone can provide here. The HTML/CSS is not my own. It was already in the project, unfortunately I can't strip it down further than this otherwise other parts of the site break.

I have posted the HTML/CSS below as well for those who would rather just read it here than over on JS Fiddle.

The HTML:

```
<div class="head-basket">
   <div class="button">Shopping Basket</div>

   <div class="basket-container">
      <form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div><input type="hidden" name="basket" value="1" /></div>
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
               <tr class="product-row">
                  <td class="item"><a href="/?r=238637" title="remove Dickies Redhawk Super Work Trousers with Free Knee Pads" class="rem">x</a><a href="/dickies-workwear/dickies-knee-pad-trousers/dickies-redhawk-super-work-trousers-with-free-knee-pads-p545.htm">Dickies Redhawk Super Work Trousers with Free Knee Pads</a></td>
                  <td class="quantity">
                     <select name="q238637" id="q238637" class="do-change">
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        ...
                     </select>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="product-desc">
                  <td class="item" colspan="2"><span>Waist Size: 30", Leg Length: 30", Colour: Black</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="tax-row">
                  <td colspan="3"><span>Item total:</span>£14.99</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="tax-row">
                  <td colspan="3"><span>UK tax at 20%:</span>£3.00</td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="total-row">
                  <th colspan="3"><span>Total:</span> £17.99</th>
               </tr>
               <tr class="spacer-row">
                  <td colspan="3"> </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="delivery info-row">
                  <td colspan="3">
                     <p><span class="bold">Free Delivery</span> to England for orders over <span class="bold">£90.00</span> (excluding tax). </p>
                     <p>Spend another <span class="bold">£75.01</span> to qualify!</p>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <div class="buttons">
            <noscript><div><input type="submit" class="button update" value="Update" /></div></noscript>
            <a href="/your-basket/" class="button tobasket action" rel="nofollow"><tt>Proceed to Secure</tt>Checkout</a>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>​
```

And the CSS:

```
.head-basket {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 190px;
    right: 0;
    top: 23px;
}

.head-basket .button {
    width: 90%;
    border: none;
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
}

.head-basket .button:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.head-basket:hover .button {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.head-basket .basket-container {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #000002;
    display: none;
    padding: 3px;
}
.head-basket:hover .basket-container, .head-basket:active .basket-container, .head-basket .basket-container:active, .head-basket .basket-container:hover {
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
}


button, .button, .button:visited {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        line-height: normal;
        position: relative;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #aaa;
        background: #000002;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#383834,#222222);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#383834,#222222);
        -ms-filter: "progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startcolorstr='#383834',endcolorstr='#222222')";
        filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startcolorstr='#383834',endcolorstr='#222222');
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #111;
        border-bottom-color: #555;
        border-left-color: #555;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
        border-width: 2px
}

button:hover, .button:hover {
        text-decoration: none; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c6c6c6; 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c6c6c6; 
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #c6c6c6; 
        color: #fff !important;
}

button:focus, .button:focus { 
        outline: 0; 
}

button:active, .button:active { 
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #c6c6c6; 
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #c6c6c6; 
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #c6c6c6;
}​
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: Yeh, we never got a working solution without using JS; although the client really isn't happy about the use of JS.

Comment: I looked at it now, and it seems to be a problem with IE. Made it very simple http://jsfiddle.net/HssXt/7/. But it still did not work. Also tried finding a workaround with no luck.

Comment: I did quite a lot of googling around at the time, and I think I concluded it was an IE bug as well.  For some reason hovering over an `<option>` seems to remove focus/hover events from it's containers.

Comment: Yes, I think IE assumed that having :focus on the <select> also means it's under the :hover state, and thus removes the :hover state from the main dropdown. It's a difficult one. I'm not sure you can fix the IE issue without using JS. I've done a fair bit of Googling and nobody has managed to find an acceptable solution. I'd replace the <select> control with an <input> instead. It's not the best solution but it'll remove your headache.

Comment: Thats exactly what I proposed to the client, but they said no.  The stupid thing is the input is for selecting the quantity of an item so you can update the basket. I really don't think a `select` is the right solution, but hey. Client gets what the client wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility of using :target selector for IE9. In you example you replace div.button with a.button:

```
   <a href="#basket-container" class="button">Shopping Basket</a>
```

Add anchor to div.basket-container:

```
<div class="basket-container" id="basket-container">
...
</div>
```

And then use :target selector to have dropdown opened:

```
.head-basket .basket-container:target {
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HssXt/10/

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t316

Though, you will need some additional close button to remove the hash from this target. And in this case, still, IE8 and below won't get any solution.

So it's inevitable. You either use JS to add some "active" class or replace select with text input.

Another thing to consider is to remove that select input from the dropdown at all. Changing quantities in cart dropdown seems like a very infrequent use-case to me. And that functionality will be on checkout page anyways (will it?), so you can simplify the interface and get rid of a problem at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately the client demanded it, so I have no choice. In the end they did accept a JS solution.  Personally, I agree, it is way over the top for a header basket on a dropdown, and who wants a `select` with 300 number in anyway?  Easier for people to type. Thanks for your solution though, really appreciated.